# Installing linux-headers-2.6.32-042stab085.20

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox

I am trying to install virtualbox-4.3 on a VPS hosting which has Ubuntu 12.04 and kernel version :

```
uname -r ==> 2.6.32-042stab085.20
```

When I try to install it, I get the following error:

```
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! Your kernel headers for kernel 2.6.32-042stab085.20 cannot be found. Please install the linux-headers-2.6.32-042stab085.20 package,
```

I know that the kernel is old and I really can't update it, unfortunately... Is there a way to install the headers for this kernel version ?

**Edit1: I have found the following in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)**

```
/lib/modules$ cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)
/lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab085.20$ ls
modules.alias      modules.ccwmap  modules.dep.bin  modules.ieee1394map  modules.isapnpmap  modules.pcimap    modules.softdep  modules.symbols.bin
modules.alias.bin  modules.dep     modules.devname  modules.inputmap     modules.ofmap      modules.seriomap  modules.symbols  modules.usbmap
```

It is strange though, since there is no include folder...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer these  links

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/313365/how-install-kernel-header-in-ubuntu?rq=1
2. http:/www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-full-kernel-source-ubuntu-linux/

The short answer is  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)  should  usually work.

Also incase this doesn't work please paste the output

Comment: The output (I have the same problem) is: `Unable to locate package`